# Does workqueue.RateLimitingInterface has Insert function for prioritizing some work items handling

Tags: kubernetes, queue, client-go

I read about "k8s.io/client-go/util/workqueue" documents and wonder, is there a way to insert the very work item in front of the queue, so that the item can be handled before others? Thanks.

Or any workround or alternatives?